# Symfony2 - Issue getting correct id to show/{id}

Tags: php, symfony

I have a view page which is passed all my active alerts.  On each displayed row, I have a show button so you can see the individual alert

```
{% for alert in alerts %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ alert[0].id }}</td>
        <td>{{ alert[0].alertStatus }}</td>
        <td>
            <input type="button" value="Show" data-url="{{ path('NickAlertBundle_show', {id: alert[0].id}) }}" onclick="show_alert( {{ alert[0].id }} )" id="show"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

So when the button is clicked, the javascript function show_alert is called.

```
function show_alert(id){
    alert(id);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: $("#show").attr('data-url'),
        data: {id: id},
        success: function(data) {
            if(data){

            }else{
                alert("Unknown Error!");
            }
        },
        error:function(){
            alert(id);
        }
    });
}
```

Now I do an alert at the top of that function, and that alert always displays the correct id.  I think the problem is with the url part of the ajax call.  It calls the data-url which should be correct.  This is what it should be calling

```
NickAlertBundle_show:
    pattern:  /show-alert/{id}
    defaults: { _controller: NickAlertBundle:Alert:show }
    requirements:
       _method:  GET|POST
       id:  \d+
```

So this should then call the controller action

```
public function showAction(Request $request, $id)
{
    var_dump($id);
    if($request->isXmlHttpRequest())
    {
        $id = (int)$request->request->get('id');
    }

    return new JsonResponse('test');
}
```

At this point though, the var_dump in this action always outputs the id of the last added alert, and not the selected alert.  And when I display the alert, it always displays the latest added alert.

So what is causing it to get the latest alert id instead of the selected id?  As I say, it initially gets the correct id, but at some point this changes.

Thanks

Comment: what is `alert[0]`? What does `alert` contain? Can you dump it?

Comment: would be better if you show how you're calling a js `show_alert` function..

Comment: I do show how the function is being called, through the buttons onclick method.

Comment: Is `data-url` being generated correctly? Did you check it (with firebug)?

Comment: one more question, where and how do you get the `alerts` variable/array?

Comment: The alerts array is passed to the viewAction.  The view page shows all alerts, but each alert has a show button.  If you click the show button for an alert on the view page, it should show the individual alert on its own page,

Comment: ok, as you told, the `alerts` array contains only one element (as you told that `id="show"` is the only id in that file), then,  that `alert` in for loop is the latest one which is causing the issue? Or it also contains the `alerts` (as you're getting the `id`  by `alert[0].id`)?

Comment: No worries, think I have found the problem.  The url in my ajax is calling the wrong data-url because all my buttons will have the same id.  If I use this instead, I am hoping this solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't declare duplicated ids, like id="show" in your template, better use `class` or declare your ids like `id="show_1 ... n"`

Comment: That was just a generic id I am using for now, but its not a duplicate, its the only id I use in that file.

Comment: Yeah but this id is in a loop. So I think it is repeated isn't it ?